# Ubuntu 18.04 error importing Opencv

Tags: opencv, 18.04

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.

When I type:

```
import cv2
```

I had an error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4:  
undefined symbol: pixaDisplayTiledInColumns
```

Comment: How did you install `cv2` python binding? I do not have any problem on clean 18.04 LTS (see my answer below).

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy python-opencv python3-opencv`, `pip list | grep cv` and `pip3 list | grep cv` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

On clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation of OpenCV Python bindings with

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv python3-opencv
```

does not have any issues. Both commands

- `python2 -c "import cv2"`
- `python3 -c "import cv2"`

terminate successfully.

**Note:** *cv2* python modules are from official packages

```
$ dpkg -S cv2 | grep python
python-opencv: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
python3-opencv: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: It still throw the error: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4: undefined symbol: pixaDisplayTiledInColumns

Answer (score 1):

This particular symbol is from liblept5, I just had the same error when upgrading mpv.
Doing an apt-get install liblept5 should fix it (it did for me).